# Use parameters with logic app for sftp connection is not working

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created an logic app and added the action SFTP - List files in folder. When I create the connection to the SFTP server it connects succesfully.

Next I have to select the folder.
I want to make use of parameters, that works fine with 1 level, but when I want to make use of /folder/subfolder then I am getting an error that the folder does not exist after running the logic app.

I have 2 questions

1. is it possible to make use of /folder/subfolder?

- if yes, how?

2. What is/are the best practice(s) to manage a lot of connections for a set of logic apps?

- In the future we will make use of more logic apps and more connections. Those connections will also be integrated in different logic apps. To manage or keep a good overview I want to know if there are best practices.

thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage Container contains below folder structure:

[image]

> is it possible to make use of /folder/subfolder?  if yes, how?

Yes, it is possible like using below connection **`deisgn`**:

[image]

With Parameters:

[image]

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Without Parameters:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

There are no best practices as such, but one needs lot of connections as there may be lot of containers.

You will get all connections when you click on change connection :

[image]

Try to use above design to get expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. In your example you are making use of the blob storage as ftp server. In my scenario I am using an external ftp server (not sure if that makes any difference between those two) and when I do exactly like you do (without giving the filename in the parameter) the ftp action is not able to find the folder /folder1/folder2. When I point to one folder like /folder1 then it is working fine. It is a weird situation :) but I will give it a try again. Thank you again. I appreciate your time.